# Unity test ads aren't showing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads

I am working on adding unity advertisements to my android game. I am following a ***out dated*** unity tutorial by unity.

My problem is that when i want to get "unity's 2D test ads on android" they don't show up on computer or `Remote 5`

**What is my code :**

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize("xxxxxxx", true);
        while(!Advertisement.IsReady())
            yield return null;
        Advertisement.Show();
    }
}
```

EDIT: By further inspection i think the fault partially might be because of the outdated video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment you'll want to remove your ID from the question and possibly request new IDs. I believe your issue is you are never calling this `IEnumerator`. Calling it `Start` does nothing as `Monobehaviours` expect a function of type `void` to be called in Unitys default execution.

Simply call the `IEnumerator`

```
private void Start()
{
      Advertisement.Initialize("xxxxxxxx", false);
      StartCoroutine(StartAd());
}

private void StartAd()
{
       while(!Advertisement.IsReady())
            yield return null;
        Advertisement.Show();
}
```

I would consider storing a reference to the `Coroutine` call so you are not ever trying to serve two ads at once, but as your example is called from `Start`, it will only ever get called one right now so it is not an issue.

Comment: @KārlisKazāks You replaced the `xxxxxxxx` with your ID again right?

Comment: @KārlisKazāks Not sure which tutorial you used, but [`this`] one should be correct. As far as I can tell the code should work as it works for me on Android, PC and iOS. Your issue is most likely passing in `true` for the parameter as that is test mode. Set it to false to enable actual ads.